# Cannot find module 'event'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

```
const EventEmitter = require('event');

const emitter = new EventEmitter();
```

**// register a listener**

```
emitter.on('messageLogged', function() {
  console.log("listen is called ");
});
```

**// raise an event**

```
emitter.emit('messageLogged');
```

Comment: It should be `const EventEmitter = require('events');` [ref](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter)

Comment: If you get the solution from these suggestions, pls select one as the answer.

Comment: i dont understand your question i am new here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try requiring 'events' with an s

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
```

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html